# Popop Box With URL Like Dribbble.com

Tags: url, callback, popup, external

**Explanation:**
I have a portfolio page with all of my graphic design I've made. I always liked the Dribbble way of showing "Shots".

**Problem:**
The problem is that I don't know how I can make the popup have an URL like on Dribbble. Dribbble opens the "Shots" in a popup box with an URL callback.

**Question:**
Can you guys point me in the right direction? What is this type of action called? I will appreciate all type of help!

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a combination of opening a popup with onclick and changing the url and opening the popup when the url has /shots in it onload. The popup content itself is loaded trough ajax.

If you want I can make an example. Do you want to load content that is already on the page in the popup or load external content?

Comment: I want to load external content. If you could make an example I would be grateful!

Comment: @JensKvist Here's a popup window that shows external content: https://jsfiddle.net/seahorsepip/j7a67wsb/8/ , I'll post an update when I've implemented url thing you wanted.

Comment: You are the best! Thank you so much. You deserve upvotes